# Imprimir en una caja de texto un resultado en TkInter

Tags: python, tkinter, get, text

comunidad, me gustaría terminar esta pequeña app para realizar pings multiples a un segmento de red, pero tengo un problema al querer imprimir el resultado en un text de tkinter este me lo imprime en la consola. Alguien aquí que me apoye por favor, ya gaste mis ideas buscando todas las palabras posibles en Google.
Quiero imprimir el resultado en

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import subprocess
import os
```

En realidad este es el código funcional para atraer el resultado de los ping, funciona en una terminal por si solo, lo demás es gráfico y es lo de menos.
Solo que quiero tener mi ejecutable y usarlo más cómodamente en el trabajo.

```
#Funciones
def ping():
    with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
        for n in range(1, 11):
            ip="192.168.0.{0}".format(n)
            result=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip],
                stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
            if result:
                #Imprimier en inactive = Text(textoiEntry)
                print (ip, "inactive")
            else: #Imprimier en active = Text(textoaEntry)
                print (ip, "active")



# Configuración de la raíz
root = Tk()
root.title("Multiple ping")
root.resizable(1,1)
root.iconbitmap('ping.ico')
```

Intente lo siguiente mas sin embargo no me funciono y me dice que es incorrecta la variable al ejecutar el codigo.

```
#getInactive = StringVar()

root.config(cursor="arrow", bg="blue", bd=15, relief="ridge")


frame = Frame(root,width=520,height=700)
frame.pack(fill="y", expand=1)#lado al que estara alineado en el frame (side="right","botom","top","left") (side=anchor="e,w,")
frame.config(cursor="pirate", bg="light blue", bd=25, relief="sunken")

label = Label(frame, text="Ping Multiple")
label.config(fg="blue", bg="lightblue", font=("Verdana",24))
label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

label = Label(frame, text="derechos reservados")
label.config(fg="blue", bg="lightblue", font=("Verdana",2))
label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

#Ingesar Segmento de red ej. 192.168.20.
segmentoLabel = Label(frame, text="Ingresa el segmento:")
segmentoLabel.config(fg="black", bg="lightblue", font=("Verdana",10))
segmentoLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

segmentoEntry = Entry(frame)
segmentoEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
segmentoEntry.config(justify="right")

#Ingesar la ip inicial
inicalLabel = Label(frame, text="Ingresa la ip inicial:")
inicalLabel.config(fg="black", bg="lightblue", font=("Verdana",10))
inicalLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

inicialEntry = Entry(frame)
inicialEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
inicialEntry.config(justify="center")

#Ingesar la ip final
finalLabel = Label(frame, text="Ingresa la ip final:")
finalLabel.config(fg="black", bg="lightblue", font=("Verdana",10))
finalLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

finalEntry = Entry(frame)
finalEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
finalEntry.config(justify="center")

#Boton ping
#Button(frame, text= "Hacer ping", justify="center", command=ping).grid(row=4, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
ttk.Button(frame,text="Hacer ping",command=ping).grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

#Titulo de text
tituloLabel = Label(frame, text="Inactiva")
tituloLabel.config(fg="black", bg="lightblue", font=("Verdana",10))
tituloLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="n", padx=5, pady=5)

#Titulo de text
tituloLabel = Label(frame, text="Activa")
tituloLabel.config(fg="black", bg="lightblue", font=("Verdana",10))
tituloLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="n", padx=5, pady=5)

#Aqui deberia ir el resultado de los ping

textoiEntry = Entry(frame)
textoiEntry.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
textoiEntry.config(justify="left")

textoaEntry = Entry(frame)
textoaEntry.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
#textoaEntry.grid(row=5, columnspan=0)
textoaEntry.config(justify="left")

inactive = Text(textoiEntry)
inactive.pack()
inactive.config(width=24,height=30, font=("Consolas",12), padx=10, pady=10, selectbackground="lightblue")

active = Text(textoaEntry)
active.pack()
active.config(width=24,height=30, font=("Consolas",12), padx=10, pady=10, selectbackground="lightblue")



#frame1 = Frame(root,width=400,height=400)
#frame1.pack(fill="y", expand=1)#lado al que estara alineado en el frame (side="right","botom","top","left") (side=anchor="e,w,")
#frame1.config(cursor="pirate", bg="light blue", bd=25, relief="sunken")


# 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente aplicas el metodo `get()`

```
print(entry.get())
```